# Does Lucene.Net support XOR boolean queries?

Tags: lucene.net, orchardcms, boolean-logic

I'm building an Orchard module that uses Lucene search but it doesn't look like it supports XOR (matches A or B but not both). Is this something I'll have to roll myself or have I missed a setting somewhere that enables it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene does not natively support XOR operations. However you can simulate this behavior by writing your query as follows:

`+(A B) -(+A +B)`

Comment: hmm - so I'll need to work out whether I can bend the Orchard searching to allow that kind of search text to be fed through to Lucene. Adding this search - `+(primary geography) -(+primary +geography)` - into the front end should have given me 11 results but only gave the one that contained `primary` and `geography`, which was the only result it should NOT have returned. This gives me a starting point to work with though - thanks Keith